# c program to list content directory with all attributes

Tags: c, unix

Current uni student and need help writing a c program that displays the contents and all information in a directory.

The listing should have the filename, mode, links, user, group size and modtime.

this is what i have completed:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

void do_ls(char [], struct stat *);
void show_stat_info(char [], struct stat *);

main(int ac, char *av[])
{
    struct stat info;   
    if ( ac == 1 )
        do_ls( ".",&info );
    else
        while ( --ac ){
            printf("%s:\n", *++av );
            do_ls( *av,&info );
        }
}

void do_ls( char dirname[], struct stat *buf )
/*
 *  list files in directory called dirname
 */
{
    DIR     *dir_ptr;       /* the directory */
    struct dirent   *direntp;       /* each entry    */

    if ( ( dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ) ) == NULL )
        fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
    else
    {
        while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL )
        {
            printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name );
            printf("   mode: %o\n", buf->st_mode);         /* type + mode */
            printf("  links: %d\n", buf->st_nlink);        /* # links     */
            printf("   user: %d\n", buf->st_uid);          /* user id     */
            printf("  group: %d\n", buf->st_gid);          /* group id    */
            printf("   size: %d\n", buf->st_size);         /* file size   */
            printf("modtime: %d\n", buf->st_mtime);        /* modified    */
            //printf("   name: %s\n", fname );               /* filename    */
        }
        closedir(dir_ptr);
    }
}
```

right now it only lists the files inside a directory but all the details come back as zero
when I pass a directory to the function it will say "can not open filename"

This is what I am trying to achieve:

if no argument is passed through the program will print all the names and the details of the current directory

if a directory is passed through the program will print the information for all files inside the directory

Comment: You haven't called `stat` anywhere. So `buf` is uninitialized.

Comment: In addition to your own error message I suggest to add `perror("opendir")` to print the system error message or use `strerror` to integrate the system error message into your own message. Please show in your question what directories and files you have, how exactly you call your program and copy&paste the exact output or error message(s). What is your current directory when you call the program? In your explanation you mention an error message "can not open filename". Do you mean the slightly different message printed by `fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);`?

Comment: You don't really need to pass `struct stat *buf` as a parameter. You can declare `struct stat info;` in `do_ls()` and then call `stat (direntp->d_name, &info);` to fill the struct for each filename. You can actually declare it within your `while ( ( direntp = readdir( dir_ptr ) ) != NULL )` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the stat pointer argument, used early return to simplify code, and called stat on each path which is build by combining the directory and file name (crudely), also fixed the format strings:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void do_ls(char dirname[]) {
    DIR *dir_ptr;
    if(!(dir_ptr = opendir( dirname ))) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ls1: cannot open %s\n", dirname);
        return;
    }
    struct dirent *direntp;
    while((direntp = readdir(dir_ptr))) {
        struct stat buf;
        char path[PATH_MAX];
        snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, "%s/%s", dirname, direntp->d_name);
        if(stat(path, &buf)) {
           fprintf(stderr,"stat failed\n");
           break;
        }
        printf("%s\n", direntp->d_name );
        printf("   mode: %o\n", buf.st_mode);         /* type + mode */
        printf("  links: %ld\n", buf.st_nlink);        /* # links     */
        printf("   user: %d\n", buf.st_uid);          /* user id     */
        printf("  group: %d\n", buf.st_gid);          /* group id    */
        printf("   size: %ld\n", buf.st_size);         /* file size   */
        printf("modtime: %ld\n", buf.st_mtime);        /* modified    */
        printf("   name: %s\n", path );               /* filename    */
    }
    closedir(dir_ptr);
}

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    if(ac == 1) {
        do_ls(".");
        return 0;
    }
    while(--ac) {
        printf("%s:\n", *++av);
        do_ls(*av);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is giving me a stat failed

Comment: when i use perror on the stat it gives me sucess>

Comment: actually when  i remove the check on stat the code works correctly

Comment: i managed to get your code to work 
but when i pass through a specific directory in the command line it says that directory can not be accessed?

Comment: Sorry, about that, I added the error check after I tested the code and inverted the test.  Fixed.  It works for the me with either with no arguments or directories specified.